# The difference between username and loginName

Tags: login, registration

In the examples they're used mixed:

[Registration](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form)

```
<input id="username" type="text" name="username"
{%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%}>
```

[Login](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/login-form)

```
 <input id="loginName" type="text" name="loginName"
    value="{{ craft.session.rememberedUsername }}">
```

For the login form, a field named "username" can not be used, it should be "loginName". What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can login with either your email address or your username.  And some sites will be [forcing](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#useEmailAsUsername) the username to be the email address.